# Wondering whether I need to installll JDK 1.6 & 1.7 together?

Tags: java, compilation, backwards-compatibility, java-6, java-7

Can I use JDK 1.7 to compile the code written in JDK 1.6? Is Java strict downward compatible?

Do I need to keep JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 together in the same machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use JDK 1.7 to compile the code written in JDK 1.6?

Yes.

> Is Java strict downward compatible?

If the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) are specified when compiling.  Those are most notably:

- `-source`
- `-target`
- `-bootclasspath` - which requires an `rt.jar` of the **JRE** (not JDK) being targeted

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use JDK 1.7 to compile the code writtern in JDK 1.6?

Yes you can.

> Do I need to keep JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 together in the same machine?

You *can* install them both on the same machine. Whether you *need* both depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Java 7 does warn you if you compile with `-target 1.6` if you are not specifying a bootclasspath pointing to Java 6: it can't check if you are using classes introduced (or changed) in Java 7 if you compile with the Java 7 libs.

Comment: @Mark *"Java 7 does warn ..if .. not specifying a bootclasspath"*  It is one of the best things about the 7 JDK (or at least javac) & very overdue IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, java has backwards compatibility.

With the latest jdk you have enought, but you can keep the two jdks without problems