# osgi bundle resolved but gives exception at run time Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: tomcat, osgi, bundle

I have a tomcat server implementing osgi framework with predeployed osgi bundles proving jsp and servlets webapps. Tomcat version used is 6.0.24. This tomcat installation comes bundled with a popular industry tool. I am not supposed to install any version of java or set JAVA_HOME for the tomcat to work. JAVA libs and bin are provided by the tool itself and the version provided is 1.6.

I am interested towards adding my own bundles into existing tomcat. So i have developed and tested a sample bundle on a different machine which has java 1.7 and the compatibility for compiler selected is 1.6, the bundle runs fine on other machine. When i deploy the bundle it has a resolved state, but when i try to start the bundle it throws the "Unsupported major.minor version 51".

UPDATE: apparently it looks i deployed an older version of the bundle which was still compiled in java 1.7, i recompiled the bundle with 1.6 compatibility and the bundle is now active.

```
    osgi> ss sample

    Framework is launched.

    id      State       Bundle
    77      RESOLVED    sample.http2_1.0.0.2

    osgi> start 77
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator sample.http2.Activator for bundle sample.http2 is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.console(FrameworkConsole.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.run(FrameworkConsole.java:224)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sample/http2/Activator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:150)
    ... 14 more
    Nested Exception:
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sample/http2/Activator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.console(FrameworkConsole.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.run(FrameworkConsole.java:224)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Nested Exception:
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sample/http2/Activator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.console(FrameworkConsole.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.run(FrameworkConsole.java:224)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

    osgi>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class file is compiled for Java 7 (version=51) but you run it (likely) on Java 6 (version=50), see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file).

So it is just the VM balking at an unknown class file. Notice that there are different compatibility settings for java. There is the Java source level compatibility and Java target compatibility. The class format file version is set by the target compatibility, see [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663450/whats-the-difference-between-source-and-target-compatibility.). In javac you want to specify -target 1.6.

You can get a more readable error before you start your app when you use the OSGi [Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment) option in OSGi.