# Ant Build error while compiling java code 1.4 with target version 1.8

Tags: java, ant

I have my project which was compiled and built using `jdk1.4`. Now I want to compile the same with `jdk1.8`.

However, build fails saying that `StringBuilder` is not found in `java.lang` package which is strange for me.
In my `build.xml` file, I have set source=1.4 & target = 1.8. Am I doing anything wrong?

`StringBuilder` was introduced in jdk1.5 and our legacy project is getting compiled  with 1.4. There are lines of code similar to the below sample.

`throw new  IllegalArgumentException("usage of String Builder ("+data.length+")");`

*I have 2 doubts here*:

1. How is the code getting built with jdk1.4? In the build.xml,I specified source and target versions to 1.4 and it builds fine.
2. Why is not getting build for any versions(source and target) higher than 1.4?

Comment: As per javadocs StringBuilder Since: 1.5

Comment: Have you modified your code since you last compiled it on 1.4? If it compiled in 1.4, it shouldn't have `StringBuilder` in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the difference between -source and -target compatibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663450/whats-the-difference-between-source-and-target-compatibility)

Comment: @shoover: The code is not modified. I have added more explanation on what I have done so far. Please check. Sorry for not giving up full info upfront.

Comment: Does your program also contain a `class StringBuilder`? If so, there may be naming conflicts and you'll have to use the full package name.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:No such class in the project