# JavaFX package does not exist in JDK 1.9 compiling to 1.8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a JavaFX project that I would want to compile to a jar such that JRE 8 and above are able to run the jar. I am using Intellij IDEA 2017 CE, running on a Mac, using JDK 9.0.1 as my project SDK.

The project compiles fine for the following gradle settings:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.9
targetCompatibility = 1.9
```

However, when I tweak the target compatibility to `1.8`:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.9
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

It shows a stream of errors relating to a missing JavaFX library:

```
Error:(1, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
Error:(2, 23) java: package javafx.geometry does not exist
Error:(3, 23) java: package javafx.geometry does not exist
Error:(4, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(5, 28) java: package javafx.scene.control does not exist
...
```

I looked at other stackoverflow answers to see why this is happening such as:

1. [JavaFX comes with JDK 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974003/javafx-comes-with-jdk-8)
   Says JavaFX is bundled with JDK 1.8 but I am using JDK 1.9.
2. [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk) Says OpenJDK has JavaFX, but I am not using OpenJDK
3. [cannot resolve symbol javafx.application in IntelliJ Idea IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178895/cannot-resolve-symbol-javafx-application-in-intellij-idea-ide) Says OpenJDK does not have JavaFX (what?), but I am not using OpenJDK

I have also tried to invalidate the caches before building the project but to no avail.

How do I compile to JRE 8 with my JDK?

Comment: What are the reasons you think that backward compatibility works this way? You're building in JDK-9 and want to run (or compile) in JRE-8? Why don't you try to write the code in JDK-6 and compile it to JDK-2 binary? I'm afraid that would be *forward* compatibility.

Comment: See this link May be help full @Moon cheesez

Comment: @zlakad I thought it works this way because after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663450/whats-the-difference-between-source-and-target-compatibility, it looks like I can tweak the target JDK version to any version I would like. Also, what do you mean that it would be forward compatible? It seems to be as I have a higher version of JDK, supporting a lower version

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/packaging-javafx-2-applications-in-intellij-idea-121/ @Moon cheesez

Comment: Well, I think if we write some code JDK-9 compatible, we cannot just compile it for JDK-8 because **some** code cannot be applied to the target. I didn't read links you provided, but IMHO **both** source and target **must** be the same. IDK if intelij-idea (or any other IDE at this point) *can* actually deal with this issue. I'd try to write the whole project using the JDK-8

Comment: @AK.Sharma I don't understand the steps in the link provided. I think the guide is for an older version of IntelliJ (The url says 2013). I also didn't configure IntelliJ to use a JavaFX template.

Comment: @zlakad According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10663507/4428725) in the post I linked, it said that "You could use a Java SE 7 compiler and compile to run on Java SE 1.5", so I assume that you can use Java SE 9 compiler and compile to run on Java SE 1.8?

Comment: I read it, but I think those answers approves what I'm thinking. Is it so hard to install/use JDK-8  and set the project properties for source and target to JDK-8 Java platform? This is the very small step...

Comment: @zlakad I see what you mean, so you are suggesting that I use JDK 1.8 to compile instead of 1.9. Your previous comments looked like you were telling me to rewrite my code to be compatible with 1.8, which I thought meant that I will have to somehow replace all my JavaFX code in 1.8. As to why those errors show up, I still find it a mystery...
Add your answer below so that I can accept it

Comment: My friend, I don't care about the reputation, so I will not convert my comments to answer. There is no mystery  - IDE developments are NOT suitable for JDK-9 (no exclusions)! I really think you should rewrite your project using the JDK-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166176/discussion-between-moon-cheesez-and-zlakad).