# In Gradle, how to publish for multiple Java versions?

Tags: java, gradle, cross-compiling

Here is a simple example: a project is using a compiler plugin "io.tryp:splain_2.13.12:1.0.2", which is compiled with Java 11 but doesn't specify Java version compatibility matrix.

When the project uses Java 8 for compilation, it will cause the following error (https://github.com/tribbloid/prover-commons/actions/runs/6202008634/job/16839860491):

```
Execution failed for task ':prover-commons:core:compileTestFixturesScala'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':prover-commons:core:testFixturesCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.tryp:splain_2.13.12:1.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :prover-commons:core
      > No matching variant of io.tryp:splain_2.13.12:1.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 8, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.12:1.0.2 declares a library for use during compile-time, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.12:1.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.12:1.0.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.12:1.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
```

When it uses Java 11 or later, this error will disappear (https://github.com/tribbloid/prover-commons/actions/runs/6202301632/job/16840784472)

This looks ridiculous, the version of the bytecode being generated by compilation & publishing should be irrelevant to the JVM runtime being used. How do I enforce the compiler to generate bytecode compatible with every Java version between 8 and 21?

Comment: As long as that's your source code you can add an option to the command line for the compiler.  If it's someone else's library then they have to do it, and if they didn't then the library is probably not compatible with earlier versions of Java.

Comment: Java `source` and `target` options: https://www.baeldung.com/java-source-target-options

Comment: Also lots here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663450/whats-the-difference-between-source-and-target-compatibility

Comment: Yes it is my source code, and I think I already have used that option in gradle: https://github.com/tek/splain/blob/c5c59cd8f25f7d6a452e84be32f0e9921afe9e3a/build.gradle.kts#L131C13-L131C32